# Wordpress: Customizing Header Image

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I'm working in a wordpress theme in which we have the usual header image. With help of CSS, it is possible to apply grayscale and brightness to such image. However, I need to enable some controls on the dashboard to let the user manage those properties as needed.

I don't know how to add those controls in the dashboard and get their value. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I was looking for, see the details in the next link. It is pretty well documented. Regards

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214512/how-to-add-css-option-to-header-image-customizer